# how to get formatted data from a array and convert it back to new array in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a data array like below. I need to format it like shown

```
a = ["8619 [EC006]", "9876 [ED009]", "1034 [AX009]"]
```

Need to format like

```
["EC006", "ED009", "AX009"]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Why WATIR tag included?

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mre]. Please be aware that [so] is not a code-writing service, you need to show your efforts!

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input

```
a = ["8619 [EC006]", "9876 [ED009]", "1034 [AX009]"]
```

Code

```
p a.collect { |x| x[/\[(.*)\]/, 1] }
```

Output

```
["EC006", "ED009", "AX009"]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
arr = ["8619 [EC006]", "9876 [ED009]", "1034 [AX009]"]
```

To merely extract the strings of interest, assuming the data is formatted correctly, we may write the following.

```
arr.map { |s| s[/(?<=\[)[^\]]*/] }
  #=> ["EC006", "ED009", "AX009"]
```

See [String#[]](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) and [Demo](https://rubular.com/r/BfVabm9RbBvWmq)

In the regular expression `(?<=\[)` is a *positive lookbehind* that asserts the previous character is `'['`. The `^` at the beginning of the character class `[^\]]` means that any character *other than* `']'` must be matched. Appending the asterisk (`[^\]]*`) causes the character class to be matched zero or more times.

Alternatively, we could use the regular expression

```
/\[\K[^\]]*/
```

where `\K` causes the beginning of the match to be reset to the current string location and all previously-matched characters to be discarded from the match that is returned.

---

To confirm the correctness of the formatting as well, use

```
arr.map { |s| s[/\A[1-9]\d{3} \[\K[A-Z]{2}\d{3}(?=]\z)/] }
  #=> ["EC006", "ED009", "AX009"]
```

[Demo](https://rubular.com/r/jfD55D1hPPgTXT)

Note that at the link I replaced `\A` and `\z` with `^` and `$`, respectively, in order to test the regex against multiple strings.

This regular expression can be broken down as follows.

```
\A        # match beginning of string
[1-9]     # match a digit other than zero
\d{3}     # match 3 digits
[ ]       # match one space
\[        # match '['
\K        # reset start of match to current stringlocation and discard
          # all characters previously matched from match that is returned
[A-Z]{2}  # match 2 uppercase letters
\d{3}     # match 3 digits
(?=]\z)   # positive lookahead asserts following character is
          # ']' and that character is at the end of the string
```

In the above I placed a space character in a character class (`[ ]`) merely to make it visible to the reader.